# Popin not getting closed in IE11

Tags: angular6, ng-bootstrap

Hello I am using ngbootstrap modal window in my angular 6, i have below code in my html to close the popin.

```
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span (click)="closePopin()">×</span></button>
    </div>
```

here is the code in .ts file.

```
import {NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

 constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}
 closePopin() {
       this.activeModal.close();     
   }
```

However this does not work on IE11, nothing happens on when we click on popin X button, n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move the `(click)="closePopin()` from the `span` element to the parent `button` element, it will work in IE11:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="closePopin()">
    <span>×</span>
</button>
```

Please see [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7pzmiz?file=app/modal-component.ts) for a demo